# reinstalling boot loader after linux partition removal

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, bootloader

The process: I had a Windows 7 partition and an Ubuntu 11.04 partition on the same  HDD. (35GB Windows 7, 400GB data, 15GB free for Linux). Windows 7 was installed first, then Ubuntu with GRUB loader.

In Windows 7, I removed the Ubuntu partition (carelessly, I must admit) to resize it, and reinstall a clean ubuntu 14.04.

In the process, it killed GRUB (and I don't remember on which partition it was installed). I was unable to boot Windows 7 anymore. So i managed to get a Windows 7 rescue shell and prompt some `bootrec /fixmbr` and now i can boot normally on Windows 7.

Problem is : Windows 7 rescue disk and stuff cannot detect any Windows 7 installation on my HD. `bootrec /scanos` or `/rebuildbcd` tells me `0 Windows installation found`!

Ubuntu 14.04.1 installer cannot find my Windows 7 installation / partition either! (And suggests a full erase disk & install, which is no good.)

How can I fix my Windows 7 boot? How do I reinstall GRUB? or Ubuntu, keeping my Windows 7 partitions?

I'm ok with installing a more aggressive Linux distro (but which one?) capable of detecting/cleaning my boot loaders and then reinstall Grub, and then I'll reinstall Ubuntu over it.

thanks

Comment: If Windows is booting fine, we can always add an entry to the GRUB menu after installing Ubuntu. For now, don't choose the full-disk-erase option, but select "Something Else" and use only the partition you kept aside for Ubuntu. Don't format the Windows or Data partitions and you will be fine.

Answer (score -2):

this site may have what you need.
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/how-to-boot-iso-with-grub2-easy-way.html..